# Creating custom launcher icons and logos in android studio

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a customized .png to display on my Action Bar and previous to this I have used the launcher icon generator in the link below. The problem with this is it generates the image I want hovering over a white shape and I want the logo to rest naturally on the Action Bar(without the white background) and when I choose the Action Bar generator it just colors in my icon. I think there is a transparency issue but I am not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions?

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the png properties with Android Studio or the IDE you're using. Transparency property must be editable.

Answer (score 0):

Select "ActionBar and Tab Icons" when creating the icon instead of "Launcher Icon".

This will allow you to create an icon (that is properly sized for the ActionBar BTW) without any background.

Comment: Yes I tried this but when creating an image from that tab everything works properly but the picture is too small. The only way I have been able to create a sizable picture is by manually saving the photo from the digital editor I am using and then checking if it is big enough.